# Display Data from a dependent dropdown in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, jscript

i need help, i'm new to php and jquery
i created a two tier dependent dropdown list populated from mysql database,which uses two tables products and fieldo with pid as the foreign key.

//code for dropdown.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><?php include "connectdb.php"; ?>
<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "states.php",
    data:'pid='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}

function showMsg()
{

    $("#msgC").html($("SELECT name, email from fieldo where state = '#state-list option:selected'").text());
    return false;
}
</script>
<body >
    <form>
    <label style="font-size:20px" >Products:</label>
        <select name="product" id="product-list" class="demoInputBox"  onChange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Products</option>
        <?php
         $sql="SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE TYPE = 'BULK'";
         $results=$dbhandle->query($sql); 
        while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) { 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rs["pid"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["Name"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>


        <label style="font-size:20px" >State:</label>
        <select id="state-list" name="state"  >
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        </select>
        <button value="submit" onclick="return showMsg()">Submit</button>
    </form>

        Result: <span id="msgC"></span><br>

</body>
</html>
```

//code for states.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">//alert("sdfsd");</script>
<body>
<?php
require_once("connectdb.php");
//$db_handle = new DBController();


    $query ="SELECT oid,state FROM fieldo WHERE pid = '".$_POST["pid"]."'";
    $results = $dbhandle->query($query);
?>
    <option>Select State</option>
<?php
    while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rs["oid"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["state"]; ?></option>
<?php

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

this list is working correctly but i want to display the other columns of stated (email , name and contact) upon selection of the state.
its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the `while` loop without breaking the PHP script? It seems you are almost trying to run a `for` loop.

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE TYPE = 'BULK'";
    $results=$dbhandle->query($sql); 
    while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $rs["pid"] . '">' . $rs["Name"] . '</option>';

    }
?>
```

### UPDATE

Okay, so I heard your comment, and I have used an `ajax` call to get the full display of the content; I was not really sure as to what you were trying to do with your `showMsg()` function. I was assuming you were wanting to create a new query request.

So I changed the function to create an Ajax call that would look something along these lines:

```
<script>
function showMsg()
{
    var val;
    val = $("#state-list").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "table.php",
        data: "state_id="+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#msgC").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And then `table.php` would be along these lines...

```
<?php
// check to see if state_id has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['state_id']))
{
    $state_id = $_POST['state_id'];
}
// if it is not set, add something in place.
else
{
    $state_id = "1";
}

// query goes here - ask for the ID
$query = "SELECT name, email from fieldo where state = " . $state_id;

$results = $dbhandle->query($query);
while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) {

    //... create table with all content;

}

?>
```

Comment: Yes mate! the drop downs work perfectly i select a product and then their respective states display in the next dropdown, what i want is when i select a state it should display the values in corresponding columns of the same table like i did in this function

Comment: function showMsg()
{

    $("#msgC").html($("SELECT name, email from fieldo where state = '#state-list option:selected'").text());
    return false;
}

Comment: Got it, what is your `officer.php`?  I think I may have something in mind

Comment: sorry, My bad! 
i renamed officers.php to states.php

Comment: @bettleJuice has explained as to why PHP cannot interect with the user at live time, you need something like AJAX to be able to create the updated connection. Downloading all of the data on-load is a way to look at your problem, I personally do not think it is a very reliable method - slower connection, more memory being used, etc...

Comment: thanks alot mate, it is working flawlessly allthough it wont display the end final results but ill figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot react to what is happening in the browser. Once PHP has processed the page and the web server has sent it to the browser, JavaScript takes over.

This means that if a customer selects a new state, it will not automatically get PHP to populate the rest of the page with the matching email, name and contact. You need to change your approach a bit.

One approach is to use Ajax. It would work like so:

1. In jQuery, register an `onChange` event handler for the states dropdown.
2. When customer selects a new state, the event handler will be triggered. Within the handler, make an Ajax request that sends the PHP the selected state.
3. the PHP document that receives the request would query for the matching email, name and contact from the DB and send the results, perhaps as a JSON
4. Back in the jQuery handler, when data comes back from the PHP server (in the response callback), use that data to populate the page with the right email, name and contact.

An alternative, even simpler approach (if you don't have a lot of data) is to have PHP send all data at once in a multi-dimensional array when the page loads. This time when the user selects a new state, the jQuery event handler will look up the data under that state within the big array, and fill the form with the data.